# Office-JS - Add comment to Excel cells

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I am looking for a way to

> add comments to specific cells/ranges in a bound table using the
>   JavaScript API for Office.

So far I have not had any luck in finding a working solution for this. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently available through the JavaScript APIs.  Feel free to suggest it here though:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks I found a previous suggestion from November 2015 and added votes/comments to that. It is a real petty that this is not yet supported as it is a requirement for an add-in I am currently translating from an older Interop Add-In for our client. So far Office.js has failed to be a complete replacement over the older Interop framework.

Comment: @MatsOftedal, thanks for adding your vote.  If you don't mind, could you expand a bit on what exact functionality you're looking for in the Comments API.  Just the ability to add/remove/edit-text of comments, or also positioning/sizing/colors/fonts/etc.  I ask because the former is certainly supported on all platforms, whereas the treatment of how comments are displayed is different across endpoints (e.g., Excel Online).

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/10742331-ability-to-manipulate-excel-comments

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have updated with a comment detailing the information requested. It is mainly add/edit/delete of comment text that is a requirement for us. We are working on translating an add-in that imports data to a set of databases directly from within Excel and comments are a very important part of the feedback to the user.